# Get the value of a field which is in an object of an ArrayList (java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList (class Library) that has two "Books" objects in it.
Inside each Book there are 4 fields: author, release date, price#1 and price#2.

I would like to sum the price#1 of all the books that are in

Comment: what did have you tried so far? post some code

Comment: Fine, sounds fairly easy - what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to write the following code:

```
int sum = 0;
for (Book book: books) {
  sum = sum + book.getPrice1();
}
```

I would of course recommend to consider checking that books is not null (i.e - have the above code in an "if" block that looks like -

```
if (books != null) {
....
}
```

Comment: Or even better, make sure that books is never null and you don't have to check any longer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public double getSumOfBooks(List<Book> books) {
  double sum = 0;
  for( Book b : books ) {
    sum += b.getprice1();
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum=0;
for(Book book : arrayList) {
  sum+=book.getPrice1();
}
return sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a one-liner if you use the [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) library.

Using [`Lambda.sumFrom`](http://lambdaj.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/apidocs/ch/lambdaj/Lambda.html#sumFrom%28java.lang.Iterable%29):

```
List<Book> books = ...;
int totalPrice = sumFrom(books).getPrice1();
```